# awk: get information on input and output filenames from file

Tags: awk

I have a file called "names.txt" that contains a list of strings:

```
apple
banana
orange
```

And I have a directory that contains filenames that contain the strings that are listed in "names.txt":

```
apple_file.txt
orange_file.txt
banana_file.txt
```

I want to perform an awk command on all the files in the directory that contain the strings in "names.txt" and end with "_file.txt" and save the new outputfile as a file that contains that same string and ends with "_better_file.txt", so basically what these three awk commands do:

```
awk '{print $1,$3}' apple_file.txt > apple_better_file.txt 
awk '{print $1,$3}' banana_file.txt > banana_better_file.txt 
awk '{print $1,$3}' orange_file.txt > orange_better_file.txt
```

Any idea on how to do this more efficiently than the three awk commands above by using the file "names.txt"?

Comment: **efficiently** you meant less process or less codes?

Comment: I mean by using a single command that uses the input file "names.txt" that is now not used in my example solution. There are hundreds of files instead of just the three that I gave as an example.

Comment: Why do you need names.txt instead of just operating on *_file.txt? Are there some *_file.txt files that you don't want to operate on and so names.txt is a subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the files to apply the `awk` command to each.

Using `for f in $(cat names.txt); do awk '{ print $1,$3 }' ${f}_file.txt > ${f}_better_file.txt; done`, it gives:

```
# cat names.txt
apple
banana
orange
# ls -1 *_file.txt
apple_file.txt
banana_file.txt
orange_file.txt
# for f in $(ls -1 *_file.txt); do echo $f; cat $f; done
apple_file.txt
foo bar foo
aze rty aze
foo bar foo
banana_file.txt
foo bar foo
aze rty aze
foo bar foo
orange_file.txt
foo bar foo
aze rty aze
foo bar foo
# for f in $(cat names.txt); do awk '{ print $1,$3 }' ${f}_file.txt > ${f}_better_file.txt; done
# for f in $(ls -1 *_better_file.txt); do echo $f; cat $f; done
apple_better_file.txt
foo foo
aze aze
foo foo
banana_better_file.txt
foo foo
aze aze
foo foo
orange_better_file.txt
foo foo
aze aze
foo foo
#
```

Or maybe you want to use only awk? In such a case, the loop solution won't comply.

Comment: `for f in $(cat names.txt); do awk '{ print $1,$3 }' ${f}_file.txt > ${f}_better_file.txt; done` has multiple fundamental shell programming errors (UUOC, unquoted variables, for f in $(command output)). The way to really write that loop would be `while IFS= read -r f; do awk '{ print $1,$3 }' "${f}_file.txt" > "${f}_better_file.txt"; done < names.txt` but it'd still be extremely slow compared to just using 1 awk command (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: wrt `for f in $(ls -1 *_better_file.txt)` - think about what that's doing vs just `for f in *_better_file.txt`. [google "parse ls output"](https://www.google.com/search?q=parse+ls+output&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and in particular read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: I'll read your docs, thank you for the links. It was a POC of looping file solution, not a copy paste to prod command.

Comment: This is the one that did it for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Give this line a try, awk one-liner, single process, no looping.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0"_file.txt"]=$0"_better_file.txt";next}
    a[FILENAME]{print $1,$3 >> a[FILENAME] }' names.txt *_file.txt
```

Hope it gives what you want.

Comment: You should really use `FILENAME in a` rather than `a[FILENAME]` for the test just in case a file name starts with `0...`. ITYM `>` btw, not `>>` - awk is not shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
NR==FNR{ ARGV[ARGC]=$0"_file.txt"; ARGC++; next }
FNR==1 { close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/_[^_]+$/,"_better&",out) }
{ print $1, $3 > out }
' names.txt
```

The above reads "names.txt" in the NR==FNR block, and for every line "foo" in names.txt it adds an entry "foo_file.txt" to the end of the array of file names that the script will operate on (ARGV[]).

The part after the NR==FNR block is where each of those "foo_file.txt" files are being operated on and step 1 is to close any previously open output file, if any, to avoid getting a "too many open files" error in some awks and then create a new output file name by adding "_better" in the middle of the current input file name so given an input file name of "foo_file.txt" it creates an output file name of "foo_better_file.txt".

Then the last line simply prints the 2 fields you're interested in from the input file into the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming any number of files *that contain the strings from **names.txt** and end with "**_file.txt**"* (may not obligatory be prefixed with `apple_`, `orange_` etc):

```
for f in $(grep -lf names.txt *_file.txt); do awk '{print $1,$3}' "$f" > "${f/_file/_better_file}"; done
```